# pandas overwrite values in multiple columns at once based on condition of values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have such DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'col0': [11, 22,1, 5]
    'col1': ['aa:a:aaa', 'a:a', 'a', 'a:aa:a:aaa'],
    'col2': ["foo", "foo", "foobar", "bar"],
    'col3': [True, False, True, False],
    'col4': ['elo', 'foo', 'bar', 'dupa']})
```

I want to get length of the list after split on ":" in col1, then I want to overwrite the values if length  > 2 OR not overwrite the values if length <= 2.

Ideally, in one line as fast as possible.

Currently, I try but it returns ValueError.

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] = df.loc[df['col1'].str.split(":").apply(len) > 2], ("", "", False), df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']])
```

EDIT:
condition on col1.
EDIT2: thank you for all the great and quickly provided answers. amazing!
EDIT3: timing on 10^6 rows:

@ansev
3.2657s

@jezrael
0.8922s

@anky_91
1.9511s

Comment: Is the condition on `col2` or `col1`?

Comment: I do apologize for the mistake. It is col1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html), add `1`, compare by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and assign list to filtered columns in list:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].str.count(":").add(1).gt(2), ['col1','col2','col3']] = ["", "", False]
print (df)
   col0 col1    col2   col3  col4
0    11               False   elo
1    22  a:a     foo  False   foo
2     1    a  foobar   True   bar
3     5               False  dupa
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it doesn't store a temporary split, but why not using `gt(1)` instead of adding 1 and `gt(2)`?

Comment: @anishtain4 - yop, agree

Answer (score 11):

You need [`series.str.len()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) after splitting to determining the length of the list , then you can compare and using `.loc[]` , assign the the list wherever condition matches:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].str.split(":").str.len()>2,['col1','col2','col3']]=["", "", False]
print(df)
```

---

```
   col0 col1    col2   col3  col4
0    11               False   elo
1    22  a:a     foo  False   foo
2     1    a  foobar   True   bar
3     5               False  dupa
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with **`expand = True`** and [`DataFrame.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) with `axis=1`.

```
df.loc[df['col1'].str.split(":",expand = True).count(axis=1).gt(2),['col1','col2','col3']]=["", "", False]
print(df)
   col0 col1    col2   col3  col4
0    11               False   elo
1    22  a:a     foo  False   foo
2     1    a  foobar   True   bar
3     5               False  dupa
```